How to resolve Metamask not asking for transaction confirmations on a mainnet fork?
Beginner to Ethereum. I'm testing out Solidity smart contracts on a fork of the mainnet which I created using Hardhat, and have used an Alchemy API Key to do so. I'm using three wallets that I created, and am using these wallets to interact with the smart contract. I've added this fork and custom network to Metamask, and have connected all accounts to Remix IDE. However, when I interact with the contract, while Metamask reflects the new balances (changing by fees to deploy and deposit, etc), it does not ask me for a transaction confirmation or show the transactions under the Activity Section. The Hardhat console shows all transactions going through. How do I resolve this?
This is the code of my hardhat.config.js
const fs = require('fs');

// Load secrets, contains the private keys
const secrets = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./secrets.json'));

// Extract values
const ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEYS = secrets.privateKeys;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.18", 
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: `https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/MY_API_KEY`, // Alchemy Mainnet network URL
      },
      chainID: 31337,
      // account creation code
      accounts: ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEYS.map((key) => ({
        privateKey: key,
        balance: "10000000000000000000000" // Set initial balance 
      })),
    },
  },
};


You are connected to Nodes using Alchemy API. This means you are not using MetaMask to prodcast your transactions. For this MetaMask does not ask for confirmations. If you want to use MetaMask, you need to use the injected provider.
To use the browser injected provider, you can either use window.ethereum according to the eip-1193 witch is the easiest. Or for a more advanced scinario, you may like to deal with Multi Injected Provider Discovery that has been specified at eip-6963

Thanks for responding, I have edited the question to include the code

I updated the answer.
All the best,

I don't think you need to write the accounts in hardhat.config.js. This way only Metamask knows the private keys so you force it to popup the interface and sign through it.
